# JPA + Hibernate маппинг множества таблиц с большим количество полей

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Только что возник вопрос. Допустим у нас имеется 20 таблиц. И каждая из таблиц имеет к примеру в среднем по 40 полей. В некоторых таблицах имена полей повторяются, в некоторых нет(ну стандартная ситуация id, name, description). Уточню, в среднем я бы мог представить что процентов 95% всех таблиц имеют до 15 одинаковых полей, а в остальных некоторые из этих 15 полей будут рандомно отсутствовать.

К примеру можно было бы воспользоваться MappedSuperclass, и объявить в нем для 95% таблиц 15 полей(то есть будет конструктор на 15 полей) и потом создавать частные Entity. Как быть с остальными 5%? Сомневаюсь что такое подойдет.

Можно через Inheritance, но мне кажется это еще хуже.

Извините за поток сознания, хз как такое объяснить точнее)
И надо найти способ как в случае чего такой кал маппить. Может есть какие-то подходы, паттерны, либо кто-то реализовывал подобное?

Comment: Когда в таблице в среднем 40 полей - это признак недостаточной нормализации БД. Любые попытки мапинга БД с плохой архитектурой могут привести только к появлению кода с плохой архитектурой.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev такие таблицы более чем возможны. К примеру банковские документы.